# How to remove item from List<Tuple<DateTime, string>>

Tags: c#, linq, list, tuples

I am trying to remove items from a list with tuples, where the first tuple item's date is before today's date.

Here's my code:

```
 List<Tuple<DateTime, string>> Events = new List<Tuple<DateTime, string>>();
```

Preferably with linq.

I fill the list like this:

```
 Events.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, string>(date, stringtext));
```

So any items in the list where the date is before december the 20th, 2016. should be removed. The second tuple(the string) doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you really want to remove the earlier items, or just create an enumeration of the items after 20 dec 2016 ?  Because obviously you can't use just linq to remove them, that would be modifying the list whilst enumerating, which would be bad.  You could use linq and `.ToList()` to create a list of the ones after 20 Dec 2016 and then assign the new list to the `Events` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, string>> events = new List<Tuple<DateTime, string>>();

DateTime date = new DateTime(2016, 12, 20);

events = events.Where(x => x.Item1 > date).ToList();
```

This will leave in your events the items which have date bigger to 20.12.2016.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need

Comment: @KevinTinnemans you can mark the answer as correct if helped you

Comment: yeah, I need to wait 15 minutes after asking the question

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to delete those from the existing list, (not by creating new list as the other solution said) here is the code:

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, string>> Events = new List<Tuple<DateTime, string>>();
DateTime date = new DateTime(2016, 12, 20);
Events.RemoveAll(x => x.Item1 < date);
```

Comment: That's a better approach (no additional collections are created)

Answer (score 1):

This uses linq and `.ToList()` to create a list of the ones on or after 20 Dec 2016 and then assigns the new list to the `events` variable.

```
events = events.Where(e=>e.Item1 >= new DateTime(2016, 12, 20)).ToList();
```